# C#/HTTP : Как сжать методом GZIP тело запроса при HTTP POST

Tags: c#, http, post, https, request

**Добрый день.**

**uncompressed_string** - сериализированный объек, json

```
            string makePostrequest(string uncompressed_string)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://............");

            var postData = uncompressed_string;
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer FKl52Ew92BCXz5ZkY0Fso3fJYf9Nr6RV7ydDX2zv");
            request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            request.Headers.Add("package-version", "2.7.2.0");
            request.Timeout = 60000;

            using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(request.GetRequestStream(), CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            return responseString;

        }
```

Но получаю ошибку:
**HTTP Error 408 Request timeout**

При открытии запроса в фиддлере первым делом получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как правильно сжать тело запроса через GZIP и сделать POST ?**

Comment: [Decompression error : The magic number in GZip header is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47513219/312041)?

Comment: Так не надо в строку перегонять, а затем опять байты получать. Передавайте в post сразу массив байт из gzipstream.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я испарвил как Вы писали, и теперь получаю 408 ошибку (request Timeout). Не знаете, как ее можно преодолеть?